# Padding and/or margin different in IE/Firefox than Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, margin, padding

Here is the problem page: http://www.alternativefreedom.com/grc275/a7/
The navigation bar looks perfect in chrome but doesn't line up along the right edge in IE or Firefox. This is how it looks:

[image: showing the bug]

Any thoughts, ideas and opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You normally want to use a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) just because of this. A source of resets: [2013’s most popular CSS Reset scripts, all in one place](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Comment: Thanx a bunch to both of you for the quick replies. However, it has put a bit of a bad taste in my mouth that my introduction and thank you to the community seems to have been removed from my question (I'm guessing to make it more concise). Is this standard procedure to have instant censorship around here?

Comment: I'm sorry that I made you feel this way, but yes, it is [common and sometimes automated for a number of reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950). Basically, a short, precise and to the point answer is preferred in StackOverflow.

Comment: Turns out I was using this website without a very complete understanding of how it works. Now that I'm no longer ignorant to the ways of this website, I no longer have a bad taste in my mouth =)
Having people make my questions better, after-the-fact, to improve my chances of an effective answer sounds awesome to me!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of rendering differences cross-browser/platforms.

To avoid this kind of problems, consider using html5 boilerplate:

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Also, take a look at this:

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

It's already included on html5bp.